# Angularjs get value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array where I would like to get an item and assign it to a variable using a function. I have the following code:

```
$scope.var1 = '';
$scope.var1 = '';

$scope.arr = [{
  'item1':'test1',
  'item2':'test2',
  'item3':'test3'
}];

$scope.myFunc = function(){
  $scope.var1 = $scope.arr.item1;
  $scope.var2 = $scope.arr.item1;
};
```

But when trying to call the function with `ng-click="myFunc()"` it does not work. Is this even possible to do? Or do I need to get around this another way?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: " it does not work" what does it do?

Comment: You have an array of objects, not a simple object. In that specific array, you'd do `$scope.arr[0].item1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$scope.arr` is an `array` with `object`(s).

So instead of

```
$scope.arr.item1
```

You have to use

```
$scope.arr[0].item1
```

Or convert your `array` to an `object` like so:

```
// Removed the brackets []
$scope.arr = {
    item1: 'test1',
    item2: 'test2',
    item3: 'test3'
};
```

Then you are able to retrieve the values like so `$scope.arr.item1;`